# Java lambda expression joining multiple terminals

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning java 8 and lambda expression, and i stumbled upon this problem, 
can you apply to count, sum, average, min and max to a list (lets say integers) all at the same time, and return as a result a string, containing all of these 5 aggregation.

So far i just found out that i have to use the `collect(Collectors.joining(","));` at the end to join these results into a string, but not how to apply these terminals all together.

Comment: check `IntSummaryStatistics`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988707/find-max-min-sum-average-lambda-java