# Find the min and max number from a Collection using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Below is the code snippet which, as expected, is failing at compile time.

What I really want to do is to find the min and max from all the lists using streams.

```
public class Delete {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 677, 0);
      List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(11, 12, 23, 34, 25, 77);
      List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(12, 21, 30, 14, 25, 67);
      List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(41, 25, 37, 84, 95, 7);

      List<List<Integer>> largeList = Arrays.asList(list, list1, list2, list3);

      System.out.println(largeList.stream().max(Integer::compare).get());
      System.out.println(largeList.stream().min(Integer::compare).get());
   }

}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988707/find-max-min-sum-and-average-of-a-list/25988761#25988761 (possible duplicate but without the `flatMap` part)

Comment: And for the `flatMap`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-using-lambdas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to flatten the elements of all the `List`s into a single `Stream<Integer>` in order for your code to work :

```
System.out.println(largeList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).max(Integer::compare).get());
System.out.println(largeList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).min(Integer::compare).get());
```

This is not very efficient, though, since you process the `List`s twice in order to find both `min` and `max`, and you can get the same data (and more) in a single processing by using `IntStream::summaryStatistics()` :

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = largeList.stream().
                                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                                      .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                      .summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(stats.getMin());
System.out.println(stats.getMax());
```

Here's another solution available since Java 12:

```
System.out.println (largeList.stream()
                             .flatMap(List::stream)
                             .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                                          Collectors.maxBy (Integer::compare),
                                          Collectors.minBy (Integer::compare),
                                          List::of
                                     )));
```

Using `Collectors.teeing` allows you to apply two `Collector`s on the same `Stream`, and then do whatever you wish on the result of the two `Collector`s. In this example the first `Collector` will compute the maximum element, the second `Collector` will compute the minimum element, and the two numbers will be collected into a single `List`. The output is a `List<Optional<Integer>>`, where the first element holds the maximum and the second element holds the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
largeList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).max(Integer::compare).get();
```